# What is the meaning and origin of the "se-" prefix?

Tags: etymology, prefix

There are a lot of Latin words that begin with [*se-*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dse2). It adds the notion of being "apart" or "separated":

- secerno
- secludo
- secubo
- seduco
- seiungo
- sepono
- etc.

The linked entry calls it an "inseparable prefix" meaning "aside / by itself." [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/se-#Latin) associates it with the reflexive pronoun *se*. There also seems to be a separate (apparently unrelated) meaning where *se* is a contraction of *sine*, e.g. *securus* = *sine cura*.

These options provoked some questions for me:

- If *se-* is related to the reflexive pronoun, how do we make sense of the "apart" meaning?
- If *se-* is a preposition, why does it only appear as a prefix? It reminds me of *secus*, but seems to have the opposite meaning.

Comment: I'd also be curious which (if any) version of *se* is related to *semel* and *simplex* etc: I could see the connection to "separated" but it's a bit of a stretch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a (rare) preposition sēd, sē “without” with the ablative (as in Old Latin sed fraude), and (more commonly) a prefix sē- “without, apart from” (as in securus etc.), and also the conjunction sed “but”. The commonly accepted theory is that these derive from some case form (ablative?) of the reflexive pronoun IE *swe-, as in Latin se, suus. The semantic development would have been something along the lines of “on one’s own” > “without”.

Comment: Very helpful! Am I correct, then, to think that the derivation from the reflexive pronoun is pretty remote, and the closer association is to the obsolete preposition *sēd, sē*?

Comment: @brianpck. Probably.