# In what sense is "securitas" a condition of being "without care"?

Tags: etymology

[This post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6607/what-is-the-meaning-and-origin-of-the-se-prefix) states that *se* is a prefix that means "without". [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/securus#Latin) coincides on that regarding the Latin word *securus*, which is described as a compound between *se* and *cura*, "without care". Some of the meanings include "careless, negligent", which make sense. I am particularly interested in the meaning "free from danger, safe, secure". In effect, the English word "security" (Spanish *seguridad*, etc) comes from *securitas*, which comes from *securus*.

What I don't get is in what sense "security" is related to "without care". Is it because when something is secure, it does not need care? Seems a contradiction to me, since security might emerge precisely because we have taken care of something. That is, security is **the outcome** of care.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last line is most telling -- it's backwards! *Securus* doesn't mean making something else safe, but rather it is the outcome of being made safe. Likewise, if something is *securus*, it's not that others didn't place care on it, but it itself lacks care.

If king is protected by a guard, the king is *securus* -- he no longer has to care about his well-being. Instead, the guard does. But we wouldn't call the guard *securus*.

Do note though that *securus* [meaning](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsecurus) "safe, secure" as opposed to "carefree, without worries" is a secondary development.